# xy_goal_tolerance: the robot reaches the goal but doesn't trigger

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I configured the Navigation stack as proposed in this [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals), but I have it seems that the server doesn't trigger when reaching the designated goal.
I played with `yaw_goal_tolerance` and `xy_goal_tolerance` (yaw = 3.14 and xy_tolerance = 1.0) but nothing... (maybe `latch_xy_goal_tolerance` is to be modified too?!?!)

As you can see from my code the client is connecting to the client like in the tutorial:

```
int counter = 0;

do{

    updateWaypoints();

    /* Define the next goal to be reached.
       For now just take the visualization marker as helper */
    next_goal_.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map";
    next_goal_.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    next_goal_.target_pose.pose = marker_array_.markers[counter].pose;

    
    ROS_INFO( "Goal [%d] is sending now...", counter ); // it is now very important to send both!...
    sendGoalAsPoint( next_goal_ );        // ...since this one goes directly to the driver to calculate height and orientation
    action_goal_.sendGoal( next_goal_ );  // ...and this one goes to the server

    bool finished_within_time = action_goal_.waitForResult( ros::Duration( 120.0 ) );

    if( finished_within_time ) {

        if( action_goal_.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED ) {
            ROS_INFO( "Goal reached!" );
        }
    } else {
        if( action_goal_.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::PENDING ) {
            action_goal_.cancelGoal();
            ROS_INFO( "Goal not reached. Deleted" );
        }
    }

    /* Select now the next Waypoint */
    counter++;

} while( counter < MAX_NUMBER_WAYPOINT );
```

I "heard" on the topic `/move_base/goal` and `/odom` and the robot reaches the pose and orientation sent to the drivers.
Since removing the client server and implementing a "manual" routine, which sends the goals comparing the actual and planned position, works everything. That means that the server or client of `/move_base` stucks somewhere, but I don't know what can I do to find where.
Any help?

UPDATE #1:
I tried to see at the output of `/move_base/feedback` and `/move_base/goal`. As you can see there no difference:

```
    /move_base/goal
goal: 
  target_pose: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1413827513
        nsecs: 677924498
      frame_id: map
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 7.08270146189
        y: -2.97619508848
        z: 2.37645603035
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.748654179258
        w: 0.662960722727
```

and here `rostopic echo /move_base/feedback`

```
  status: 1
  text: This goal has been accepted by the simple action server
feedback: 
  base_position: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1413827562
        nsecs: 543686202
      frame_id: map
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 7.08269246838
        y: -2.97619141834
        z: 2.37645603031
      orientation: 
        x: 5.69693569291e-08
        y: 1.81862260271e-08
        z: 0.748654179258
        w: 0.662960722727
```

Anyway the output of `/move_base/result` doesn't display anything. Simply the goal will never reached. Every check like `.isServerConnected()` gives a positive answer.
Could be a problem due to different namespaces? Or what could I check?

UPDATE #2:
Thank to Hendrix' idea I've implemented such a function in my code, to see the state of the goal seen by `/move_base` (/rosout doesn't output any message from /move_base)

```
...
if( action_goal_.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::ACTIVE ) {
   ROS_INFO( "Goal not reached, but ACTIVE" );
}
...
```

Of course...I ve written the same function for every possible state listed [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#a6a2baa3674db5ab9b187783371209bd3).
For every goal I get the message that the goal is **ACTIVE**. So it seems that move_base doesn't recognize the reached goal. But it waits that the defined time expires:

```
bool finished_within_time = action_goal_.waitForResult( ros::Duration( 30.0 ) );
```

and then outputs the state of the goal. Furthermore move_base doesn't seem to output any helpful information:

[image: image description]

I could implement the routine on my onw, but then I would miss the functionylities of move_base and of the navigation stack implemented in ROS.
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195300/xy_goal_tolerance:-the-robot-reaches-the-goal-but-doesn%27t-trigger/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
move_base is missing the map update rate and control loop targets by a factor of about 100x. Are you sure your robot is moving and reaching the goal at all? Are you running this on a real robot or a simulator?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
in a simulator: RViz to be precise.
The goal is visualized through a small colored box, so it is easly identified. The robot flies to that point and stops there. To me is the point reached and the above coordinates say the same.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
rviz is not a simulator.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
then I don't know what you mean with simulator. I ve not a robot at disposal.
Anyway even reducing the control loop frequency to 5.0 Hz, doesn't change anything. The problem still persist.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
rviz is only a visualizer; it displays your data, but it is not a physics engine or a sensor simulator. Perhaps you're using gazebo as your simulator?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
I m not so far. (for using Gazebo). I found RViz really useful and simple to use.
I m going to investigate this problem deeply. It can't be so difficult...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
It is not possible to use rviz as a simulator. There must be some other node that is generating your sensor data and simulating the motion of your robot.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
Ah! Ok, I didn't implement any sensor till now and the robot is moving (simulated) with a driver, written by myself. It works everything apart the navigation stack

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
Are you using your own local planner or one of the ones that is built into move_base?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
neither...nor...the driver listens to the /cmd_vel outputted by move_base but it is only subscribing to that topic since the driver (written on my own) will move the robot to the goal (it receives on a separate topic the coordinates) and publishes the odom position. Now it is very late here...

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-20**:
...tomorrow I m going to investigate much deeper. My intuition says me, that the problem is somewhere else. Bye!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
That's a completely inappropriate way to use move_base, and violates almost all of the implicit software contract that it provides. You might as well be writing your own navigation system.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
You've also left out so many important details about your system that I'm no longer willing to spend time answering your questions.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-21**:
Sad that you feel a little bit upset. I think there has been a misunderstanding due to my previous post regarding "my controller". It is a simple robot_driver copied from another existing one. Taking a look to this navigation tutorial:

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-21**:
[Link](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=overview_tf.png) it says: **"..and the blue components must be created for each robot platform."** And this is what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I got it.**
Sometime should one sleep before trying to find impossible theories.
Anyway, here the explanation.

A robot driver publishes [odom informations](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) on a basis of the actual position and velocities, in order to use the navigation stack.
I was maybe too tired and didn't realize that I wrongly put in my odom message the same position information in the velocity field.

Instead of writing correctly the following line of code:

```
//set the position
odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

//set the velocity
odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;
```

I put stupidly:

```
//set the position
odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

//set the velocity
odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
odom.twist.twist.linear.x = x;            <= Velocity HERE
odom.twist.twist.linear.y = y;            <= Velocity HERE
odom.twist.twist.angular.z = 0.0;         <=  Angular Velocity HERE
```

So... ***WHAT HAPPENED?!?!?***

It happened that the controller moved the robot in the right position, same frame, always correctly, **BUT** the **published velocities couldn't never get zero**!!!. So move_base couldn't trigger the server since it thought that the position must be **continuously** adjusted.

Writing the right speed variables in the odom field, corrected the error.

Now the server triggers!

Many thanks to all the people who helped me for their suggestions.
Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-08-01**:
I think I'm having the same problem as you, but I don't quite understand your solution. What do you mean by "the position must be continuously adjusted"? Does the x and y velocity have to be zero for the server to successfully complete the move goal?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2016-08-02**:
Simply don't put your position information in the velocity field. Otherwise the controller cannot reach and mantain the wanted position. But it is best that you post your code.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-08-02**:
Ah I see. I'm definitely not touching the velocity so it shouldn't be a problem. I've documented my problem as best I can [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/240877/under-what-circumstances-will-actionlib-not-mark-a-movebasegoal-as-successful/)

**Comment by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on 2016-10-25**:
Using gazebo it doesn't work, the odom twist is always not zero (if this is the problem).
Anyone solved it?